# How could this Integration be solved? Any possible Steps.

Tags: integration

$$
\int \frac{\cos x + x\cdot \sin x}{x\cdot (x + \cos x)}dx
$$

Any steps leading to a simple answer would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I would begin by splitting it up into two integrals.

Comment: @ErikMiehling can you show a few steps? I am really poor at integration but I need to solve it partially ti impress my boss!

Comment: You can split the fraction if it helps: $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{sinx-1}{x+cosx}$  (And it DOES help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\cos x + x \sin x}{x(x + \cos x)}dx$

$\displaystyle = \int \dfrac{x+\cos x}{x(x+\cos x)}dx + \int \dfrac{x\sin x - x}{x(x+\cos x)}dx$

$\displaystyle= \ln|x| - \int \frac{d(x + \cos x)}{x+\cos x}dx = \ln \left|\frac x{x+\cos x}\right| + c$.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: plus x, minus x.. very interesting! eagle eyes

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln\left|\frac{x}{x+\cos x}\right|$$

Just a minute and I'll bring you the proof.

Comment: Well.. It is already answered..